# Determine quicktime version with C#

Tags: c#, quicktime

I am writing a C# application and I need to determine if quicktime is installed on the system and what version.
This is on windows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A quick Google search turned up the following code from [this page](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2007/04/18/how-can-i-tell-which-version-of-quicktime-is-installed-on-a-computer.aspx):

```
strComputer = "."

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("Select * From Win32_Product Where Name = 'QuickTime'")

If colItems.Count = 0 Then
    Wscript.Echo "QuickTime is not installed on this computer."
Else
    For Each objItem in colItems
        Wscript.Echo "QuickTime version: " & objItem.Version
    Next
End If
```

"But wait!" you say, "That's VBScript, not C#!" That's true, but it's VBScript that does WMI queries. Another quick Google search turns up [how to do WMI queries from C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms186146%28v=VS.80%29.aspx).

Comment: Clever, indeed. Even if you don't know VBScript, it's still decent  pseudocode for the C# version.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
using (RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"))
{
    if (key != null)
    {
        foreach (string subKeyName in key.GetSubKeyNames())
        {
            using (RegistryKey subKey = key.OpenSubKey(subKeyName))
            {
                if (subKey == null) continue;

                var displayName = subKey.GetValue("DisplayName") as string;

                if (displayName == null || !displayName.Equals("QuickTime")) continue;

                var version = subKey.GetValue("DisplayVersion");

                Console.WriteLine(displayName);
                Console.WriteLine(version);
            }
        }
    }
}
```